# Will EasyChair preprints be automatically indexed by Google Scholar?

Tags: citations

Is anyone aware if a preprint uploaded to EasyChairs [preprint server](https://easychair.org/publications/preprints) will automatically be indexed by Google Scholar, or do I need to manually add the citation to my profile?